# Close drawer by clicking active selection with jQuery.GI.TheWall.js

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am using [Gold Interactive's jQuery.GI.TheWall.js plugin](https://github.com/Goldinteractive/jQuery.GI.TheWall.js) on my site to open a series of drawers that replace one another based on the selection made.

Right now, whenever a selection is made its corresponding drawer opens and the only way that that drawer can be closed (rather than replaced by another content drawer) is via a button in the drawer. This is fine; however, it is much more intuitive to simply click the same selection and have the drawer close. Issue: I can't seem to work out how to do this by myself.

It would be incredibly helpful if someone could help me work out how to close the drawer by clicking a selection that has its drawer actively displayed.

Thank you very much.

The webpage I have the plugin installed on for added example: [www.projectshft.com/whatisshft.html](http://www.projectshft.com/whatisshft.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.GI_TW_fullimg' ,function() {
    wall.hideExpander();
});
```